How and why did Natsuko end up in the tower?
In The Boy and the Heron, Mahito goes looking for his aunt Natsuko and finds her in a "delivery room" in the tower. At this point, he believes that someone took her there.
It also seems possible that no one forced her to her to enter the tower—and it is hard to think of who could have—and indeed, when Mahito tries to get her to go back, she initially angrily rebuffs him. However, a sentient tower held together only by the will of an antisocial wizard stacking blocks seems like an unusual place to choose to give birth, to put it mildly.
How did Natsuko end up in the tower and why?
